# How to fix Device Definitions not responding

Tags: javascript, xml, android-studio, layout

I am working on a app and i wanted to view what it looks like on different devices, but it seems like its only my current device definition it allows.
I have tried to inspect it and i found error concerning the implementation of my foreground drawable which it says will not be usable in API lower than version 23 which i made the required changes to them  but i just don't understand it
here is what it shows me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMC02.png)

please how can i fix this issue
hers is what my code looks like:

```js
package com.polawa.glowingagesacademy;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class elearning_page extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageButton mainpagee;
    private ImageButton googleclick;
    private ImageButton khanbutton;
    private ImageButton elearnclick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_elearning_page);
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        tools:context=".elearning_page">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mainpagee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.532" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mainpagee"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mainpagee"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="GAA e-Classroom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:fontFamily="casual" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="656dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fafaffaf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/googleclick"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="81dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/google_classroom_png_4"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.046" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/khanbutton"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:background="@drawable/khan_academy"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/elearnclick"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/elearnclick"
            tools:targetApi="m" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/elearnclick"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="79dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:background="@drawable/e_learningfor_kids"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/googleclick"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/googleclick"
            tools:targetApi="m" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please show me the build.gradle file
you can first of all enter the required sdk version there. dont forget to change the target sdk version.

then go to tools. click on sdk manager. there you can install the required sdk version.

i recommend you to use sdk version greater than 28.

Comment: I made those changes earlier before asking this question

Comment: Initially the issue was my app runs perfectly on Android version 9.0

Comment: But when I tried it on version 6.0 on this activity it crashes tried rewritten the code, inspection it not jus working

Comment: Minsdkversion is 14

Comment: And target is 29

Comment: hey. sdkversion and target version as i remember needs to be the same.